# Blockblog: Azure ---- Data transfer

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

Our team created a Premium storage account and eventually stored 126M blobs (30TB) using Blockblob.

Storage account type: Premium
Format: BlockBlobStorage

We tried Lifecycle management but it didn't work (Doesn't support Blockblob). Our job is to move data from Premium(expensive) to a low-cost (cool tier or standard storage account).

Can someone share their experience on how they performed data transfer from Premium(BlockBlog) to cool tier or to a standard/cool-tier account?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> We tried Lifecycle management but it didn't work (Doesn't support
> Blockblob).

As mentioned in the other answer, Blob Lifecycle Management is indeed supported to Premium Block Blob accounts. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#feature-support.

The issue that you have is that the cool and archive access tiers are not supported for Premium Block Blob accounts. Only hot access tier is supported in such accounts. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#feature-support.

Considering cool access tier is not supported in Premium Block Blob accounts and you can't really use Blob Lifecycle Management feature to move blobs across different account (Premium to Standard), what you would need to do is copy the blobs from your Premium account to a Standard account. While copying you can set the access tier of the blob to cool so that the blobs are copied with cool access tier. Once all blobs are successfully copied, you can delete the blobs from your Premium account.

Answer (score 0):

Since Block Blob is basically the default blob type (others being Page blobs and Append Blobs), I don't think it is correct that Lifecycle management doesn't support Block Blob. In fact, I have an account with Lifecycle management that moves Block Blobs from Cool to Archive tier automatically.

1. [Optional] Set an Account to "Cool" tier:
   [image]
2. Use Lifecycle Management and add a Rule to change Tiers:
   [image]

[image]